# How to represent values of Crypto-Coins (Bitcoins, etc...)

Tags: php, bitcoin, currency, significant-digits

Problem I face: **How to work with Money in PHP if currencies are Bitoins, Litecoins, Etherum and others alt-coins?**

This problem in case of fiat money is solved mostly by representing money as `int` in the smallest unit (cents, etc...).

- Implementation for example looks like: https://github.com/moneyphp/money

But as crypto-coins are represented mostly as number like `0.0235678` and the ***smallest unit* is not so clear**.

Yes, for Bitcoins there are Satoshi, Etherum has Tether and other crypto coins are similar mechanics. But as those currencies **are designed to be deflationary**, there is *theoretical* chance that the **smaller units will be needed** in the future.

I would like to solve this too.

Exact numbers are very often represented as `string`. And therefore using of http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php came up to my mind.

- Does anyone have any other alternative?
- Or there is some implemention of `Money` object in PHP (I didn't find any).

Now, I see only option to implement my own `Money` object internally using `bcmath`.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Ordinarily, you can use a `CURRENCY` data-type (in an SQL database) to represent "currency-amounts of any sort." Although concrete implementations vary from product to product, all of them are specifically designed to consider the problem of "fractional pennies." For example, the MS-Access database stores currency amounts as long-integers that are multiplied by 1000. This gives you four *fixed-point* digits to the right of the decimal. Integer math is functionally equivalent to BCD. Although "the currency in question" is exotic, the problem itself is old-hat.

Comment: P.S. You should also bear in mind that "PHP is rather mathematically-stupid." It really only knows about floating-point.

Comment: Mike, thanks for replay. But I am trying to solve how to represent bitcoin money in PHP not SQL.

Also, I don't want "fixed" number of digits on the right, I need possibility to have infinite of them if need and also avoid precision problems. `bcmath` in PHP works internally with strings and can provide that. But I am not sure if there is other option or if I didnt overlook something.

Comment: Very definitely, I would move the data to an immediate representation of "String." (Definitely use a library like `bcmath` or what-have-you.) What you want to be sure to stay *far away* from ... is "PHP's floating-point." Although I am certainly no expert in this subject-area, my *intuitive* notion is that you're on a good track. Move the coin-tokens immediately to a *string-based* representation, then use a BCD-math llbrary to handle them from there. Seems to me ("albeit, from a bit of a distance") that this is likely to be a good wager.